# Divs not showing on clicking the ellipsis

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well there are two cards and an ellipsis within it , onclicking the ellipsis it should show the div i.e. div with id = report.But it is not working for me. i tried the following as mentioned below in the code but it didn't work for me. Please have a glance and hope experts will help me in this regard.

```js
const ellipsis = document.querySelectorAll(".ellipsis");
ellipsis.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const report = event.currentTarget.querySelector("#report");
    report.classList.toggle("show");
  })
)
```

```css
.main{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  gap:20px;
}
.card{
  width: 150px;
  height:200px;
  background: coral;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
}
.card h4{
  color:#fff;
  top:35%;
  left:40%;
  position:absolute;
}
.card .flag {
  top:0;
  right:15px;
  position:absolute;
}
.flag #report{
  display:none;
  float:left;
  background: #fff;
  padding:0;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.flag #report.show{
  display:block;
}
.card .flag button{
  border:0;
  background:0;
  outline:0;
  font-size:25px;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
}
#report p{
 padding: 2px 5px;
  top:-10px;
  font-size:10px;
  line-height:0.1rem;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
    <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
    <div id="report" class="report">
      <p>Report</p>
      <p>Not-Interested</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
    <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
    <div id="report">
      <p>Report</p>
      <p>Not-Interested</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet here shows an error message as soon as either of those two get clicked, I would assume you get the same in your actual test environment ... so go and fix the error. If you are unclear about what it means - do a bit of research.

Comment: FYI: IDs must be _unique_. That is the very first mistake that you need to fix here.

Comment: ids must be unique! what does that mean? different id name for each card?

Comment: It means no two ids on any elements can be the same.

Comment: @mykaf got you. my bad

Answer (score 2):

The `currentTarget` in the event handler will hold the `.ellipsis` button and the subsequent `querySelector` searches for the “report” div *underneath* the button (when it is actually a sibling).

[MDN on `Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector):

> The **querySelector()** method of the Element interface returns the first element *that is a descendant of the element on which it is invoked* that matches the specified group of selectors.

Quick and dirty fix would be invoking `parentElement.querySelector` instead.

```js
const ellipsis = document.querySelectorAll(".ellipsis");
ellipsis.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const report = event.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelector(".report");
    report.classList.toggle("show");
  })
)
```

```css
.main{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  gap:20px;
}
.card{
  width: 150px;
  height:200px;
  background: coral;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
}
.card h4{
  color:#fff;
  top:35%;
  left:40%;
  position:absolute;
}
.card .flag {
  top:0;
  right:15px;
  position:absolute;
}
.flag .report{
  display:none;
  float:left;
  background: #fff;
  padding:0;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.flag .report.show{
  display:block;
}
.card .flag button{
  border:0;
  background:0;
  outline:0;
  font-size:25px;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
}
.report p{
 padding: 2px 5px;
  top:-10px;
  font-size:10px;
  line-height:0.1rem;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
    <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
    <div class="report" class="report">
      <p>Report</p>
      <p>Not-Interested</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <div class="flag">
    <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
    <div class="report">
      <p>Report</p>
      <p>Not-Interested</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also changed “report” from being an ID to being a class as already noted since there is more than one instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few bugs.

1. `<div id="report">` you can't use the same id more than one time.
2. Javascript should be fired after page is loaded.
3. Read about function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling

Try this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style>
    .main{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      display:flex;
      gap:20px;
    }
    .card{
      width: 150px;
      height:200px;
      background: coral;
      border:1px solid #000;
      position:relative;
    }
    .card h4{
      color:#fff;
      top:35%;
      left:40%;
      position:absolute;
    }
    .card .flag {
      top:0;
      right:15px;
      position:absolute;
    }
    .flag .report{
      display:none;
      float:left;
      background: #fff;
      padding:0;
      margin-top: 27px;
      margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .flag .report.show{
      display:block;
    }
    .card .flag button{
      border:0;
      background:0;
      outline:0;
      font-size:25px;
      color:#fff;
      position:absolute;
    }
    .report p{
     padding: 2px 5px;
      top:-10px;
      font-size:10px;
      line-height:0.1rem;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener ( 'DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
      const ellipsis = document.querySelectorAll(".ellipsis");
      ellipsis.forEach((el) => {
        console.log ( el );
        el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {        
          const report = event.target.nextElementSibling;
          report.classList.toggle("show");
          console.log ( report );
        });
      });      
    } );  
  </script>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="card">
      <h4>Card</h4>
      <div class="flag">
      <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
      <div class="report">
        <p>Report</p>
        <p>Not-Interested</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h4>Card</h4>
      <div class="flag">
      <button class="ellipsis">&#8942</button>
      <div class="report">
        <p>Report</p>
        <p>Not-Interested</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet leaves an opened `.report` visible until the user clicks `.ellipsis` again. It might be advantageous to use the [MDN: The Details disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) as this element has a built-in 'open'/'close' mechanism, whithout the need for extra Javascript manipulation.

The pseudo code for your `.card`:

```html
<card>
   <details>
      <summary></summary>
      <report></report>
   </details>

   <content></content>
</card>
```

```css
card           { position  : relative }
details        { position  : absolute; z-index: 1 }
summary        { list-style: none }    /* remove default marker  */
summary::after { content   : '\22ee' } /* custom ellipsis marker */
content        { /* whatever fits the card*/ }
```

All you have to do is position the report (`absolute`) over the content (`z-index: 1`) when opened, while the browser handles the 'open/close' toggling. All `<details>` will retain their current `[open]` state until the user toggles it again by clicking the `summary`.

No specific Javascript required, however, should you decide that only one `.report` can be open at a time, you *will* need to implement Javascript to handle the closure of already opened `.report`. Below snippet shows how that could be implemented (with a checkbox to toggle the behavior on/off).

*FYI, I removed the duplicate ID mentioned by others...*

Here's how I would implement the above, using your example:

```js
/*
   When only one .report can be open at a time use
   below Javascript, otherwise it can be safely removed.
*/
var currentDetail;

document.querySelectorAll('.card .flag summary').forEach(el => {
    // this event triggers before <details> 'toggle' event
    el.addEventListener("click", event => {

        // if only one can be open, close the currently opened details 
        if (getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--only-one') == '1') {

            const closest = event.currentTarget.closest('.card details');

            if (closest.open) {
                currentDetail = null; // all summaries closed
            }
            else { // not null and a different summary
                if ((currentDetail) && (currentDetail != closest)) {

                    currentDetail.removeAttribute('open'); // close current open summary
                 };
                 currentDetail = closest; // save new opened summary
            };
        };
    });
});

/* Just for checkbox operation: simply remove all 'open' attributes */
function collapseDetails() { document.querySelectorAll('.card details').forEach(el => { el.removeAttribute('open') }) };
```

```css
body {
    cursor: default; /* just the default arrow everywhere */
    --only-one: 0;   /* default false: all <details> can be [open] */
}

.main {
    display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

.card {
    position: relative; /* new stacking context for '.report' */

    /* For easy centering of content */
    display: grid; place-items: center;
    width: 150px; height: 200px;

    background-color: coral; color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.flag { /* details */
    position: absolute; z-index: 1; /* inside .card, on top of content */
    inset: 0 10px auto 55px;        /* shorthand for top/right/bottm/left */
    /* .report 80px wide (given the .card width, margin, etc.) */
}
.flag[open] { /* details 'open' specific styling */ }

.ellipsis { /* summary */
    list-style: none;   /* remove HTML default triangle marker */

    width: max-content; /* HTML default is equal to <details> width */
    margin-left: auto;  /* force to right side of .flag */
    margin-right: -5px;

    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: right;  /* only relevant when width is set to a value */

    cursor: pointer;
}
.ellipsis::after { content: '\22ee' } /* the vertical 'ellipsis' */
/* hex unicode as dec shows an Asian character */

.report { /* disclosed details content */
    background-color: #fff; color: #000;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.report p {
    margin: 0; /* remove HTML default margin */

    padding: 2px 5px;

    font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* demo stuff */
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* All these still get overridden by Firefox */
summary:where(::before, ::after, ::marker, :active, :focus, :focus-visible),
::-moz-focus-inner, ::-moz-focus-outer {
    outline: none !important;
    border :    0 !important;
    outline-color: transparent !important
}
```

```html
<label>only one 'report' open at a time&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"
       oninput="document.body.style.setProperty('--only-one', (this.checked) ? '1' : '0');
                collapseDetails();">
</label>

<div class="main">
    <div class="card">
        <details class="flag">
            <summary class="ellipsis"></summary>
            <div class="report">
                <p>Report</p>
                <p>Not-Interested</p>
            </div>
        </details>

        <h4>Card</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <details class="flag">
            <summary class="ellipsis"></summary>
            <div class="report">
                <p>Report</p>
                <p>Not-Interested</p>
            </div>
        </details>

        <h4>Card</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <details class="flag">
            <summary class="ellipsis"></summary>
            <div class="report">
                <p>Report</p>
                <p>Not-Interested</p>
            </div>
        </details>

        <h4>Card</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you work on my codes?

Comment: @mits what do you mean, work on your code? There is already an answer that solves your problem using your code. Mine shows just an alternative to what your code does without the need for Javascript.

Comment: it looks like your code is more useful....so please work on my code and onclicking one the second should dissappear.